# error "The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Box"

Tags: java

So I have no idea why vol and boxes[i] isnt multiplying, Im trying to get the dimensions of my boxes which I have already done and the volume of each individual box using a loop, that needs to be in the box class for some reason according to my professor

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Box[] boxes = new Box[5];

    boxes[0] = new Box(2.5, 1.2, 2);
    boxes[1] = new Box(1.5, 1.2, 2);
    boxes[2] = new Box(2.5, 1.2, 0.5);
    boxes[3] = new Box(3.5, 2.1, 0.3);


    for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("The dimensions of box " + (i + 1) + 
                           " is..\n" +  boxes[i]);
    }
    Box.volume(boxes);
}
}


public class Box {

   private double length;
   private double width;
   private double height;


Box(double length, double width, double height) {
    this.length = length;
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
}

public String toString() {
    return "l: " + length + "\n" + "w: "+ width + "\n" + "h: " + height;
}




//SETTERS AND GETTERS

public void setLength(double length) {
       this.length = length;
   }

public double getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setWidth(double width) {
       this.width = width;
   }

public double getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
       this.height = height;
   }

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}



  public static void volume(Box[] boxes) {
      int vol = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length - 1; i++) {
          //vol = vol * boxes[i];
      }
  
    System.out.println(vol);
    }   

}
```

The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Box

Comment: Yes? It's quite clear: You can't multiply a number by a `Box`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i see but idk how to get the content from the arrays and multiply them, from a method in a different class

Comment: 1) It is not actually in a different class.  You have declared the `volume(Box[])` method inside the `Box` class, so it could access the fields of a box directly.  2) Since you have declared getters on `Box` for the height and width, you should be able to use them.

Comment: @StephenC well i kinda fixed it  but now im getting this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method volume(Box[]) from the type Box", would I have to change everything to static? sorry btw im new to java

Comment: You could change it to a `static` method.  (And I don't think it needs to be a method of `Box` either.)  Alternatively, you could make it an instance methof that computes the volume of *this* `Box` and then do the looping and summing somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance method `boxVolume()` should be implemented to calculate the volume of specific box, and then this method needs to be called inside static method `volume`:

```java
// class Box

public double boxVolume() {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height;
}

public static double volume(Box[] boxes) {
    double total = 0.0;
    // use for each loop to iterate boxes array
    for (Box box : boxes) {
        if (null != box) {
            total += box.boxVolume();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```